# Updating versions in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I have an apk with versionCode 18 at beta tests and with versionCode 17 at production.

I do not want to upload the version from beta tests to production, because there is a bug.

Is there a way to remove this version and upload a new one or do I have to upload an apk with versionCode 19? I have found a hidden button to reject version in the HTML console. However, even if change the visibility of that button, I am still not able to use it.

How will Google Play update my version if I will upload version 19? Will it upgrade firstly to 18 and then to 19 or straight from 17 to 19?

I do not have any permission changes.

Comment: `have to upload an apk with versionCode 19` is the only way. It will updatre to highest available version (if user has 17, and 18, 19 are available, it will update to latest)

Comment: That's the reason why we first upload the build to beta because it is not fully stable build. So if they force you to release the beta build then no point of beta. Hence if move an apk to production then only it will be available for production. So no worries there it will update to version 19.